# Scraping Tripadvisor attractions using scrapy and python

Tags: python, css, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape TripAdvisor's attractions, but I cannot get the names and addresses of each attraction. I suspect I wrote *product.css(...)* wrong (there are jsons?).

Can anyone tell me how to correct the code to get the name and address of each attraction?

My current code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g187427-Activities-oa90-Spain'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.EsZYd a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(link.get(), callback=self.parse_categories)

    def parse_categories(self, response):
        products = response.css('div.eeqnt')
        for product in products:
            yield {
                'name' : product.css('h1.WlYyy cPsXC GeSzT::text').get().strip(),
                'address' : product.css('span.WlYyy cacGK Wb::text').get().strip(),
            }
```

Updated code (exporting infro from each atrraction on each page from list):

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-a_allAttractions.true-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa30-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa60-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa90-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa120-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa150-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa180-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa210-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa240-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa270-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa300-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa330-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa360-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa390-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa420-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa450-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa480-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa510-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa540-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa570-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa600-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa630-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa660-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa690-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa720-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa750-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa780-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa810-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa840-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa870-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa900-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa930-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa960-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa990-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1020-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1050-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1080-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1110-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1140-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1170-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1200-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1230-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1260-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1290-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1320-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1350-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1380-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1410-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1440-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1470-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1500-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1530-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1560-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1590-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1620-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1650-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1680-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1710-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1740-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1770-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1800-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1830-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1860-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1890-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1920-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1950-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa1980-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2010-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2040-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2070-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2100-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2130-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2160-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2190-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2220-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2250-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2280-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2310-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2340-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2370-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2400-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2430-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2460-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2490-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2520-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2550-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2580-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2610-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2640-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2670-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2700-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2730-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2760-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2790-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2820-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2850-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2880-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2910-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2940-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa2970-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa3000-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa3030-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa3060-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa3090-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa3120-Slovenia.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g274862-Activities-oa3150-Slovenia.html'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
            for link in response.css('.EsZYd a::attr(href)').getall():
                yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_categories)

    def parse_categories(self, response):
        yield {
            'name': response.css('h1.WlYyy.cPsXC.GeSzT::text').get(),
            'reviews': response.xpath('(//*[@class="cfIVb"])[1]//text()').getall(),
            'address': response.xpath('(//*[@class="dGWve"])//text()').getall(),
            'url': response.url,
        }
```

Comment: your code `'h1.WlYyy cPsXC GeSzT::text'` is searching `<h1 class="WlYyy"> <cPsXC> <GeSzT>`. It treats `cPsXC` and `GeSzT` as tag names. You have to use `.` like `'h1.WlYyy.cPsXC.GeSzT::text'` to search `<h1 class="WlYyy cPsXC GeSzT">`

Answer (score 2):

It's not really related to python, but css-selectors.

CSS classes should separate with dot and not space `WlYyy.cPsXC.GeSzT`.

Best suggestion would be to use chrome with dev-toolbar. It will give you an ability to get path to the specific element via css-selector or xpath, just right-click on the element in a DOM-tree and select copy menu-item.

Avoid using classes (especially one without semantic meaning) as an anchor point. They might change from page to page, or in time.

Better to use semantically meaningful nodes, like in your case:
XPath for the title would looks like this `//main//header//div[@data-automation="main_h1"]//h1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `for loop`   in each listing page

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g187427-Activities-oa90-Spain'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.EsZYd a::attr(href)').getall():
            #print(link)
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_categories)

    def parse_categories(self, response):
       
    
        yield {
            
            'name' : response.css('h1.WlYyy.cPsXC.GeSzT::text').get(),
            'address' :''.join(response.xpath('(//*[@class="hxQKk"])[1]//text()').getall()[:-1]),
            'url':response.url
            }
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess(QuotesSpider)
    process.crawl()
    process.start()
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why the result of my updated code (added in my question) shows less attraction than tripadvisor says? And some of them are missing or have incorrect number of reviews?

Comment: @Aisyram each url contains a lots of listing  with next pages along with link of each listing page